# Require statement in main.coffee file not working properly

Tags: coffeescript, twig

I'm trying to implement clipboardjs into a project and to do so I have the clipboardjs.js file located in ./modules/clipboardjs.js.  In the main.coffee file the line require './modules/clipboardjs' is implementing the file.  Then I have two twig templates one with a macro initializing the clipboardjs object like so:

```
<script>
  new ClipboardJS('{{ selector }}');
</script>
```

and the other being the main template file that has all the logic to produce the url.  I was having success with a different implementation but now that I'm trying to use the main.coffeescript file to import the js file it's not copying at all.  Any thoughts on what I might need to do to get this file loaded properly?

EDIT:

I've tried both solutions by changing the requires statement to `ClipboardJS = require './modules/clipboardjs'` and `window.ClipboardJS = require './modules/clipboardjs'`
and both times the errors I'm getting in chrome are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ClipboardJS' of undefined
at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (clipboardjs.js:15)
at Module.<anonymous> (clipboardjs.js:7)
at Module../src/scripts/administration/modules/clipboardjs.js (admin.js:190240)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:724)
at fn (bootstrap:101)
at Object../src/scripts/administration/main.coffee (main.coffee:14)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:724)
at fn (bootstrap:101)
at Object.1 (admin.js:192117)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:724)

articles:2332 Uncaught ReferenceError: ClipboardJS is not defined
at articles:2332
(anonymous) @   articles:2332
```

It seems like when I call the ClipboardJS constructor it's not finding the code it needs.

EDIT 2: 
@caffeinated.tech I'm not entirely sure, I'm a new dev, but I know they use webpack and gulp.  Is there a way to check?

Comment: It looks like `window` may be undefined in your coffeescript contenxt. Could you tell me how you are building / compiling your front end code? Is it `webpack`? How is the `coffeescript` being compiled?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem with scope. In Javascript, a class / variable / function defined at the top level will become globally available in all other scripts in your project.

But in coffeescript, these are scoped within the file, so cannot be used outside the file they are defined in.

You should be able to fix it by assigning the imported ClipboardJS to the global `window` object (If you are doing any server side rendering, you will have to use `global` as a fallback to `window`)

```
window.ClipboardJS = require './modules/clipboardjs'
```